# JavaFX logging for java 1.8.0_192

Tags: java, logging, javafx, log4j

I want to maximise the logging from JavaFX.

I've found and set this as a flag for the JVM:
-Djavafx.pulseLogger=true
(which produces a lot of information)

I'm trying to use log4j:

Are the options below valid? They don't seem to produce anything in my output file?

```
<logger name="com.sun.javafx">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="javafx">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>
```

Comment: JavaFX doesn’t use Log4J, so Log4J settings won’t affect JavaFX’s logging.

Comment: Ah OK thanks - how do I log from JavaFX then?

Comment: Use LogManager.getLogManager().[updateConfiguration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#updateConfiguration(java.io.InputStream,java.util.function.Function)) to read a properties file with the overriding logging confuguration.  Note that [INFO](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Level.html#INFO) is already the default logging level.  If you want a lower level, you need to configure both the Logger and each of the root Logger’s Handlers.

Comment: Thank you I will try this. Place as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFX, like all of Java SE, does not use Log4J, but instead uses the [Java logging system](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/package-summary.html).  Log4J configuration will not affect JavaFX’s logging.

You can use LogManager.getLogManager().[updateConfiguration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#updateConfiguration(java.io.InputStream,java.util.function.Function)) to read a properties file with the overriding logging configuration:

```
try (InputStream loggingProperties =
    MyApplication.class.getResource("logging.properties")) {

    LogManager.getLogManager().updateConfiguration(loggingProperties);
}
```

(Note that readConfiguration *replaces* the entire logging configuration, whereas updateConfiguration amends your customizations to the configuration.)

If you just want to change logging for JavaFX, you can do something like this instead:

```
private static final Logger javafxLogger = Logger.getLogger("javafx");
static {
    javafxLogger.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
}
```

The Logger needs to be retained in a field, or it will be garbage collected (quickly) and the customization will be lost.

Regardless of which of the above approaches you use, setting the level of the Logger is not enough.  [Handlers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getHandlers()) also have their own levels, and they too are set to Level.INFO by default.

The easiest way to address this is to set all of the Handlers’ levels:

```
for (Handler handler : Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers()) {
    handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to VGR's answer above, this is what I did to get javafx logging out at a detailed level:

```
private static final java.util.logging.Logger javafxLogger = 
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("javafx");   

javafxLogger.setLevel(Level.FINEST);

FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("MyJavaFX.log", (1048576 * 30), 1000);

fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
javafxLogger.addHandler(fh);
```